# Program won't end

Tags: python, chess

I have tried to make a program which can play random chess moves against Stockfish. When running the program, it will play the entire game and give the result, but the program won't stop running after doing this. Does anybody know what is wrong and how to fix it?

```
import random
import chess.engine
import pydirectory

board = chess.Board()

engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(r"C:\Users\qenij\stockfish\stockfish_14.1_win_x64_avx2")

def random_play():
    while not board.is_game_over():
        if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
            m1 = random.choice([move for move in board.legal_moves])
            uci = m1.uci()
            print("Play:", uci)
            board.push_uci(uci)
            print(board)
        else: 
            result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.05))
            board.push(result.move)
            
        
    print(board.result())

random_play()
```

Comment: does it print the line `print(board.result())`, or get stuck in the loop?

Comment: Is this line `print(board.result())` run?

Comment: The line print(board.result()) is run.

Comment: Then the problem is not in the lines that you have shown us. Is there anything else written after the `random_play()` at the bottom? How exactly did you run the program?

Comment: This is the entire document, it was run in vscode on python 3.9.6.

Comment: what does `print(board.is_game_over)` show? (add right after the ` print(board.result())`)

Comment: It prints 'True'

Comment: If the last print shows then it can’t be an issue with the code, how do you run the code? What happens exactly that makes you say the program won’t end?

Comment: what does the class chess.Board do?

Comment: Is there a method in chess.engine that has to be called to close  the engine process after ```board.is.game_over() == True```?

Answer (score 0):

You can quit the engine with `engine.quit()`. Also you can define board and engine inside the function.

```
import random
import chess.engine
import pydirectory


def random_play():
    board = chess.Board()
    engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci(r"C:\Users\qenij\stockfish\stockfish_14.1_win_x64_avx2")
    
    while not board.is_game_over():
        if board.turn == chess.WHITE:
            m1 = random.choice([move for move in board.legal_moves])
            uci = m1.uci()
            print("Play:", uci)
            board.push_uci(uci)
            print(board)
        else: 
            result = engine.play(board, chess.engine.Limit(time=0.05))
            board.push(result.move)
            
    engine.quit()           
    print(board.result())    
    

random_play()
```